# "NSInvalidArgumentException [__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil" error when trying to add AVPlayerItems to an AVQueuePlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a piece of code where I'm trying to add items to an AVQueuePlayer iteratively, as follows:

```
for (int i = tempNowPlayingIndex - 1; i < [_itemsForPlayer count]; i++) {
        [self insertItem:[_itemsForPlayer objectAtIndex:i] afterItem:nil];
    }
```

`_itemsForPlayer` is a `NSMutableArray` containing AVPlayerItems.

Whenever I reach this line on execution, however I get a

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

error. I know that the line responsible is

[self insertItem:[_itemsForPlayer objectAtIndex:i] afterItem:nil];

because commenting that line out removes the error. I had assumed that the problem was that `[_itemsForPlayer objectAtIndex:i]` wasn't returning an AVPlayerItem, but adding a print statement to print `[_itemsForPlayer objectAtIndex:i]` gives me:

```
<AVPlayerItem: 0x2002be60, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x2003c0e0, URL = ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=8966039988459606203>>
```

So the code should be able to add it to the AVQueuePlayer just fine. Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Many thanks to @borrrden, who answered the question in a comment - I've overridden insertItem:afterItem elsewhere in the class, and the error was coming from an issue in the overridden method. Talk about your stupid mistakes - thanks again, Borrrden!

Comment: _itemsForPlayer[i] is nil, that is the problem.  Did you forget to actually initialize _itemsForPlayer?  Ok with the bottom part that doesn't make sense, did you override insertItem:afterItem: ?

Comment: Oh, wow, I did, and had completely forgotten to look there - and, of course, the error was in my overridden function. Thanks so much!

Comment: The actual problem is that this question was tagged "Xcode" whereas it clearly doesn't have the slightest relation to Xcode.